# Reduce noise before scratch detection

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, canny-operator

I'm trying to detect the weak scratch on the chip. And also connect those non continuous scratches so that the scratch count is correct.

Currently, I am using canny edge and probabilistic hough transform to detect and draw the scratch. However,  the noise is too much for an accurate detection. I have tried with morphology operation to reduce the noise but it failed because the weak scratches will be eliminated too. Also, I have tried with sobel filter and gaussian blur to reduce the noise, but also end up with a bad result. I am quite new to image processing so i have run out of ideas to reduce the noise.

Original
[image: scratch_chip]
Expected 
[image: expected_out]

Here is the image that I am trying with. The expected outcome would be the scratch from the top of the chip all the way down to the bottom of the chip and the scratch count should be only one.

[image: attempt]

This is the best i can do with canny edge which give me wrong detection.

[image: attempt]

This is binarize image with threshold of 185

I am open to any suggestions so that i could have a try on other methods.
Also, tell me if any extra information are needed.

**EDITED**

Non local filter
[image: attempt]
 Result
[image: attempt]

Hi, i have tried with non local filter and this is the result. It is quite ok but not perfect yet especially the missing part in the middle. I solve it by manually decrease the threshold of hough transform. Is there any better way i can do with this?

Comment: What do you have in OpenCV that can help?

Comment: I only know how to use the basic filters such as gaussian and sober filter, any better filter for this?

Comment: The SE site "Signal Processing" might be more adapted to this question

Comment: Have you tried non-local filtering like neighborhood filtering? A range based filter (mean +- delta becomes mean, global or local) could also help.

Comment: @user6556709 I think what you mean is fastNlMeansDenoising() function in opencv, right? It seems to be working, will get back to you once i try with it.

Comment: @user6556709 Thanks for your suggestion, it works quite well but it also filtered out the middle part. Any idea to solve that?

Comment: What you post as "original" is not the original image, it's a screen shot of the original image displayed on screen. You should post the true original image if you want people to be able to help you well.

Comment: I'm not aware how OpenCV implemented that filter but I think they used the more or less traditional way. Without the parameters you've used it becomes very difficult to tell you, what gone wrong.